Change the array size of SGE array job
I want to qalter an array job in SGE in order to reduce the submitted array.
When I type:
qalter -t 4047-4200 103335 
(when waiting arrayis from 4047-4400)
the output is:
found lonely '-t 4047-4200' option (The -t option needs a leading job name).
Have no idea what is going on what leading job name qalter requires (no info in docs at all...)
